# google chart show only integer on vaxis that starts with zero, equal spacing, non repeat data points

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using google Chart:

I have to show only integer on vaxis that starts with zero, equal spacing, non repeat data points.

I tried following

```
vAxis: {          
        gridlines: {
            count: -1 
        },
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0
        }, 
        format: '#'
    },
```

but getting -1, 0, 1 data points on vaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use option --> `vAxis.ticks` -- to show specific axis labels

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  var ticksY = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    data.addRow([i, i]);
    ticksY.push(i);
  }

  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    vAxis: {
      ticks: ticksY
    },
    height: 600
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```